# Can't install Scrapy - working compilier not found during cffi 0.8.6

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, osx-leopard

I'm trying to install Scrapy, but it fails and I can't figure out what to do.  I'm pretty novice at command line and python.  It appears to be failing due to a package called cffi not being compiled.  I'm running Mac OSx 10.5.8.  Xcode version 3.0 installed.

Does anyone have any idea why this is failing or what I can do about it?  Thanks!

-Matt

Here's the output when I try to install using pip:

```
$ pip install scrapy
Downloading/unpacking scrapy
  Downloading Scrapy-0.24.4-py2-none-any.whl (444kB): 444kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking pyOpenSSL (from scrapy)
  Downloading pyOpenSSL-0.14.tar.gz (128kB): 128kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/pyOpenSSL/setup.py) egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
Downloading/unpacking six>=1.5.2 (from scrapy)
  Downloading six-1.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking queuelib (from scrapy)
  Downloading queuelib-1.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking lxml (from scrapy)
  Downloading lxml-3.4.1.tar.gz (3.5MB): 3.5MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/lxml/setup.py) egg_info for package lxml
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Building lxml version 3.4.1.
    Building without Cython.
    Using build configuration of libxslt 1.1.12
    Minimum required version of libxslt is 1.1.12, found 1.1.23
    Building against libxml2/libxslt in the following directory: /usr/lib

    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.py'
Downloading/unpacking w3lib>=1.8.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading w3lib-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Downloading/unpacking cssselect>=0.9 (from scrapy)
  Downloading cssselect-0.9.1.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cssselect/setup.py) egg_info for package cssselect

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
Downloading/unpacking Twisted>=10.0.0 (from scrapy)
  Downloading Twisted-14.0.2.tar.bz2 (4.3MB): 4.3MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/Twisted/setup.py) egg_info for package Twisted

Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1 (from pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cryptography-0.7.1.tar.gz (247kB): 247kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography

    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
Downloading/unpacking zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from Twisted>=10.0.0->scrapy)
  Downloading zope.interface-4.1.2.tar.gz (919kB): 919kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/zope.interface/setup.py) egg_info for package zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking cffi>=0.8 (from cryptography>=0.2.1->pyOpenSSL->scrapy)
  Downloading cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz (196kB): 196kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi/setup.py) egg_info for package cffi
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi/setup.py", line 86, in <module>
        ask_supports_thread()
      File "/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi/setup.py", line 49, in ask_supports_thread
        ok = config.try_compile('__thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/config.py", line 230, in try_compile
        self._check_compiler()
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/config.py", line 103, in _check_compiler
        customize_compiler(self.compiler)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 171, in customize_compiler
        _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler
        _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler
        "Cannot locate working compiler")
    SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi/setup.py", line 86, in <module>

    ask_supports_thread()

  File "/private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi/setup.py", line 49, in ask_supports_thread

    ok = config.try_compile('__thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;')

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/config.py", line 230, in try_compile

    self._check_compiler()

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/config.py", line 103, in _check_compiler

    customize_compiler(self.compiler)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 171, in customize_compiler

    _osx_support.customize_compiler(_config_vars)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 418, in customize_compiler

    _find_appropriate_compiler(_config_vars)

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/_osx_support.py", line 191, in _find_appropriate_compiler

    "Cannot locate working compiler")

SystemError: Cannot locate working compiler

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/gY/gYFQRMkVEYeji6ED8rcjFE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip_build_Farrell/cffi
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/Farrell/.pip/pip.log
```

Edit: Here is the result when I try to 'brew install python':

```
$ brew install python
```

Error: /usr/local/Library/Formula/openssl.rb:128: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
Please report this bug:
    http://git.io/brew-troubleshooting
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:65:in `require'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:65:in`klass'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:50:in `get_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:198:in`factory'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:32:in `to_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:88:in`expand'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependencies.rb:9:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependencies.rb:9:in`each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:76:in `expand'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:501:in`recursive_dependencies'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:98:in `verify_deps_exist'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:91:in`prelude'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:144:in `install_formula'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:67:in`install'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:67:in `each'
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:67:in`install'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:136:in `send'
/usr/local/Library/brew.rb:136

Comment: did you try "pip install cffi" ?

Comment: Identical error when trying to install cffi directly...

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed `brew install python`

You can check more details from http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Comment: I mean there s a default python on mac but you d better install the homebrew version for scrapy. Also you might need to add pip install python-dev

Comment: Hm, interesting.  I thought I had already done brew install python successfully, but I figured, might as well just try again and make sure.  Can't paste the result in here as its too long, but will add it as a new comment below this.

Comment: Added it as an edit on the initial post.  Here's the results when I try to do pip install python-dev:

`pip install python-dev`
`Downloading/unpacking python-dev`
`  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-dev`
`Cleaning up...`
`No distributions at all found for python-dev`
`Storing debug log for failure`

Comment: Well this is not a scrapy issue anymore. And I am afraid I am not qualified to diagnose brew install issues. You d better repost a new question about brew install python